# tcp port receive slow data in java but in php it receive fast

Tags: java, performance, sockets, networking

I am making a listener in java and using a thread. This works and it receives the data, 
but it receives the data very slowly for this particular listener. I do not understand this point because this Java listener works very fast for another client, and when I am using a listener written in PHP for same source, it receive data very fast. *Why would there be this speed difference?*

use parameter
send data  by client in byte array
(the actual data is in hexadecimal which is converted into a byte array and sent by client)

Why is my java code always slow?

**I spend lot of time on this and found that This JAVA Listener is slow for Tracker device
but it work proper for temporary client which send data for define port and ip.
but for Tracker device PHP Listener is fast I am not understand this point
Why would there be this speed difference for this tracker device
Please help**

my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import pack.*;
import java.lang.String;
import second.*;

public class ServerSocketExample {
    private ServerSocket server;
    private int port = 3333;

    public ServerSocketExample() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("errore on port");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        ServerSocketExample example = new ServerSocketExample();
        example.handleConnection();
    }

    public void handleConnection() {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");

        //
        // The server do a loop here to accept all connection initiated by the
        // client application.
        //
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                new ConnectionHandler(socket);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    static int count = 0;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
         t.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        String input = null;
        try {
            int i = 0;

            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
            byte[]data = new byte[42];

            int len = dis.read(data);
            socket.close();

            System.out.println("Message ");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Some code snippets would be very useful

Comment: SO doesn't condone name calling -- call it "special" data... :)

Comment: Have you _verified_ that this isn't a problem with different network speeds between various clients and services, especially if you've got multiple deployment hosts about? It's so easy to miss something obvious like that…

Comment: One idea: It could be a stupid way of reading (i.e. each byte individually or such), instead of reading greater blocks or a BufferedInputStream. But yes, please show your reading code.

Comment: No code, vague story.. please rephrase this answer!?

Comment: I ran your code through `Lindent` to get it to line up properly, and removed all the code that was commented out -- if it isn't necessary to see the problem, then feel free to leave it out. Reducing problems to the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem is a skill well worth cultivating. :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple shots in the dark.

I was writing some excel tools a while back for a company that used PCs,Macs, and *NIX on the desktops and noticed my larger data transfers between Excel and the data servers were timing out consistently on some machines but worked fine everywhere else. The only pattern I ever saw was that older versions of Windows vista and prior Windows versions seemed to have the issue most of the time and later versions of Vista and later Windows versions were usually fine.

Also make sure your co-worker aren't running bit torrent clients to download every episode of "The Simpsons" in 1080i at Warp 10 while trying to work with the online reports.

Answer (score 1):

You're not buffering your `InputStream`. This may or may not be a problem in some setups, depending on many factors.

But give it a try:

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making bigger your Socket input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

- Call System.out.flush() after each println(), because Java/SO can buffer the output and this can be a trap for fools since things looks slower than they actually are.
- Instead of creating a thread for each socket, use a [thread pool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).
- Design your protocol so a client can reuse a connection if messages are separated by short periods.